# Contact form 7 issue with jquery - hiding/showing fields

Tags: jquery, plugin-contact-form-7

I've followed [a tutorial](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-this-is-how-to-showhide-fields-with-jquery) regarding how to hide/show Contact Form 7 fields using jQuery.

I have used this before and it worked wonders. However, on a new site for some reason it isn't working. The page in question [is here](http://saintsfoundation.co.uk/application-form-for-charitable-support/).

The fields hide okay but don't show when a field conditioned to show is clicked! Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?
Here's the code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<p>You are an employee or official representative of a charity or community group (i.e. you are not a third party raising funds on their behalf (required):<br />
    [select* criteria-question-1 label_first include_blank "Yes" "No"]
</p>

<p>The fundraising will benefit people in the Southampton and/or Hampshire area (required):<br />
    [select* criteria-question-2 label_first id:form include_blank "Yes" "No]
</p>

<div class="hide" id="hide1">
    <p>Name of organisation (required):<br />
        [text* org-name placeholder "Enter organisation name here"]
    </p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    //Hide the field initially
    $( "#hide1" ).hide();

    //Show the text field only when the third option is chosen - this doesn't
    $( '#form' ).change( function() {
        if( $( "#form" ).val() == "Yes" ) {
            $("#hide1").show();
        }
        else {
            $( "#hide1" ).hide();
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue very well may be `noConflict`. By default whenever WordPress enqueues jquery it runs in a `noConflict` mode which means that it doesn't provide an alias for `jQuery` where the default is `$` as you have in your question.

[See this Dev Resource comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#comment-1473):

> When you enqueue script that is dependent on jQuery, note that the jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode, which means you cannot use the common $ alias. You must use the full jQuery instead. Alternately, place your code using the $ shortcut inside a noConflict wrapper.
>    - [bcworkz](https://profiles.wordpress.org/bcworkz/)

Which means you need to replace your `$( document ).ready()` with:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
```

---

In addition, according to your comment it looks like that ( by viewing the page source ) that you are adding in your script before JQuery is defined. If you're using the normal [`wp_enqueu_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) ( which you should be using / learning to use ) you need to define `jquery` into the `$deps` array:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-irrelevant-handle',                                  // Script handle to identify your script
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . /my-script-path.js,     // Path to your script relative to style.css
    array( 'jquery' ),                                       // Tells WordPress to add this script after JQuery has been added
    '',                                                      // Optional version number
    true                                                     // Load this into the footer for speed purposes
);
```

[This looks like a good enqueuing tutorial](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-scripts-and-styles-wordpress-enqueueing/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice Howdy_McGee, however, this hasn't resolved the issue. I used the code on my wedding website, here: [http://charlesandporsche.wedding/#rsvp] for the 'Are you a day or evening guest' field and it works without any issues. Any idea on what might be stopping it from working?

Comment: @charlieg007 you're adding your script before JQuery has been added - see my edit.

Comment: I take it that the enqueuing code provided should be added in functions.php, but how would the code look using my example? Also, should I then remove the header reference to the jQuery? Thanks.

Comment: @charlieg007 Follow the tutorial in my link at the bottom of the answer - that will walk you through adding the enqueue. Whenever you reference the jquery dependency in the function above, WordPress will automagically move it to where it needs to go ( above your script ).

Comment: I think I've now implemented this, however, it does not appear to have fixed the issue. Can you help?

Comment: @charlieg007 Doesn't look like you've implemented it correctly. It may be more beneficial to create a new question with your `wp_enqueue_script()` code and the issues you're having - that tutorial I've linked should be pretty spot on though.

Comment: This may not even be causing the issue, so it may not be worthwhile. As said the code has worked for me before on a different site. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @charlieg007 This is probably the issue. If you're using a modern browser, inspect element shows a JS error of `jQuery not defined` which usually means that you're trying to use jQuery functions before it's been loaded ( which it certainly is in this case ).

Comment: Can you kindly clarify where the enqueue code needs to go? This is the only thing that is confusing me.

Comment: @charlieg007 `This code should be placed in the functions.php file of our theme, child theme, or in a plugin file.` - this is what the tutorial says - there's also a **hook** that needs to be added which is also in the tutorial.

Comment: I'm hoping this looks okay? function my_assets() {
 'hidefieldsScript',                                  
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . /js/hidefieldsScript.js,    
    array( 'jquery' ),                                       
    '',                                                      
    true 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );

Comment: I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /var/www/vhosts/saintsfoundation.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/onetake/functions.php on line 168